# cancel Task inside Future (async/await with combine)

Tags: swift, error-handling, async-await, future, combine

I decide to use async/ await with the Combine framework.
I used an extension on the Future class and put a Task block inside it.
It seems OK, and I get a result or error, but I have a problem with this, If I want to cancel progress on my async function only I canceled the publisher.

I used below the extension and I learned on [https://tanaschita.com/20220822-bridge-async-await-to-combine-future/](https://stackoverflow.com)

```
extension Future where Failure == Error {

    convenience init(taskPriority: TaskPriority? = nil, asyncFunc: @escaping () async throws -> Output) {
        self.init { promise in
            Task(priority: taskPriority) {
                do {
                    let result = try await asyncFunc()
                    promise(.success(result))
                } catch {
                    promise(.failure(error))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and write two helper functions for saving data into core data (for example):

```
func saveIntoCoreData() throws {
        throw DatabaseError.canNotSave
    }

    func doSomeThing() async throws -> String {
        return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            do {
                Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 5)
                try saveIntoCoreData()
                continuation.resume(with: .success("Result"))
            } catch {
                continuation.resume(with: .failure(error))
            }
        }
    }
```

and finally, I called these methods with Future and I expected to get a cancel error and stop running for saving data into core data but just got a canceled event from the publisher, and data was saved into core data.

```
cancelable = Future(taskPriority: .userInitiated) { [weak self] in
            return try await self?.doSomeThing()
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
            .sink { completion in
                switch completion {
                case .finished:
                    print("Finished")
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            } receiveValue: { value in
                print("result: \(value)")
            }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
            self.cancelable?.cancel()
        }
```

I used try `Task.checkCancellation()` but the task is not canceled and did not work.

Does anyone have an idea to stop the Task?

Comment: Do you mean capturing the task in a variable `let my_task = Task{...}` followed by cancelling the task `my_task.cancel()`?

Comment: @ScottThompson I put how to use the function, and I do not have direct access to Task because it is declared inside the Future extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Futures can't be canceled, but Publishers can.

Use [Ian Keen's AnyPublisher extension](https://gist.github.com/IanKeen/934258d2d5193160391e14d25e54b084)

Then you can:

```
extension AnyPublisher where Failure == Error {
    init(taskPriority: TaskPriority? = nil, asyncFunc: @escaping () async throws -> Output) {
        self.init { subscriber in
            let task = Task(priority: taskPriority) {
                do {
                    subscriber.send(try await asyncFunc())
                    subscriber.send(completion: .finished)
                } catch {
                    subscriber.send(completion: .failure(error))
                }
            }
            return AnyCancellable { task.cancel() }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but your extension is not correct and AnyPublisher does not initialize with closure.
Thanks again for sharing the extension and AnyPublisher on GitHub, but this extension is not useful for my purpose because I need to put the async await approach inside it.
Maybe, I must change my approach, I do not know.

Comment: You need *both* extensions. The one I posted above uses the one in the link. It compiles and does exactly what you want. Look again.

Comment: Oops! I was wrong, and your response is correct. Sorry, I made a mistake, and I did not read it completely. thank you again.